# Using rsync + cron to sync a machine behind a firewall with my dropbox

Tags: cron, rsync, firewall, nfs, dropbox

I have a machine (A) behind a firewall with no access to the Internet, on this machine I can NFS mount directories on another machine (B) which can access internet, and is accessible from Internet, but I cannot install anything on this machine (B).

I want to keep a directory on (A) in sync with my Dropbox (that I use on all my other machines (not A or B), all of them connect to Internet regularly).

The solution that I came up with is to have a `cron` job on (A), to call two `rsync` commands to sync a directory on (A) with an NFS mounted directory which is actually on (B).

Then I can have a cron job on some other machine on the Internet that syncs my Dropbox with the directory on (B).

Anyone can see any problems with this plan, or has a better suggestion?

Anything other unix utility besides `cron` and `rsync`?

Comment: Can you run programs on B? If so, what programs are available? If not, how do you hope to use B as a relay between A and the Internet?

Comment: I can SSH into B and can run programs on it, but don't have root access to it, or cannot install anything new on it, it's a rather standard Redhat (or fedora, or centos?!) box.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - is B a computer on a university network or something like that? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/docs.html) to synchronize your files.  Unison uses the rsync protocol and can run over ssh.  You may need to copy the executable into your directory on the remote system.

Using `rsync` may cause problems as it is difficult to synchronize file deletions.

EDIT:  To sync a folder on A from system C (with working Drobox) a chosen directory on B becomes the hub and A and C two spokes.  Schedule the steps so that only one is running at a time.

- Schedule Unison on system C to sync to the directory on B.
- Schedule Unison on system A to sync to the directory on B.  (May require NFS mounting the directory.)
- Periodically, check Unison for conflicts if automatic resolution wasn't configured.

There are other ways to handle this.  If the directory on B is alway mounted when you need it, then you can skip this step.  A symlink to an autofs NFS mount would handle this.

p.s. I was working with WinSCP today, and found it has a synchronize function.  It appears to be useful for periodic use.  Unison still seems better for automated updates.

Comment: thanks, It looks like Unison is not being actively developed, do you use it or have you used it before?

Comment: I'm using it, and there isn't much left to be done on it.  I would only expect bug fixes or platform additions.  But I it covers all the platforms I would need.

Comment: I got it and it works perfectly, so basically you are suggesting that i replace `rsync` with `unison`? Which is a great suggestion. Still I need to mount my NFS mounts and then use `unison` to sync them, correct?

Comment: @Ali Use rsync for unidirectional synchronization, unison for bidirectional synchronization. With both utilities, all you need to have is the one binary; even if the system administrator hasn't installed them, you can easily copy that one binary to your account (and if it's not in your default `PATH`, see [How can I set environment variables for a remote rsync process?](http://superuser.com/questions/207200/207262#207262).)